# AWS Elastic Beanstalk GUI: Query failed to deserialize response

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

after running AWS Elastic Beanstalk application for few weeks suddenly I can't open my application. Page simply displays an error which doesn't provide much information how to fix it.

```
Error

A problem occurred while loading your page: AWS Query failed to deserialize response
```

(and there is no more information, Googling also haven't found any answer)

So before updating my subscription and starting paying to Amazon not insignificant amount of money for being able to contact their technical support I thought I will ask here first if someone here encountered this issue.
Thanks for any suggestions.

[image: Error after clicking on Application]

Comment: I would post this on aws forums:https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=86

Comment: Seems to be happening to me as well today.

Comment: I'm having this problem today too. If others are seeing this today I guess there is a problem at Amazon

Comment: having this problem today too. can't list the environments now, anyone found a solution or know the way to debug this?

Comment: found the issue - the region is different that's why couldn't list properly

Answer (score 1):

After receiving this generic error, I was able to dig into the actual error message by using the EB CLI. In my case the CLI threw "ZIP does not support timestamps before 1980".